# Converting from base 2 to base 10 through division

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I'm having hard time because of this exercise, I have to implement an algorithm that repeatedly, through continuos divisions, from the remaining of the divisions I can find(looking backward the remaining) the integer in base 10.

Comment: Is this what you mean:  Starting with your number $N$ write out the first division by $10$ as $N =10*N_1+r_1$. Then $r_1$ is the "units place" of your base $10$ expression.  Then repeat (So $N_1=10*N_2+r_2$ to get the "tens place" and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you start with the number in base 2 called x.

You get the lowest order digit (right most digit) base 10 by taking x modulo 10
then set x=Floor[x/10] and repeat.

For example let x = 110011 = 51
51-10*5= 1
Or in binary
$$\tag1 110011-1010*101 = 1  $$
so the first digit is 1 and we set x = 101 (from the previous step) and repeat
$$\tag2 101 - 1010*0 = 101$$
so the next digit is 5
then we set x = 0 and see that we can stop.

If it is clear how to obtain equations 1 and 2 then it should be clear how to implement this as an algorithm

Comment: how 110011 became 10011? it's a mistake?

Comment: Ah yes, It was a Mathjax syntax mistake I didn't give the tag a number so it took the next available number. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To convert from base $10_2$ to base $1010_2$ by division, you keep taking remainder repeatedly:

$$\begin{array}{rcr}
1010\quad\underline{)\quad10\ 1011\ 0001\quad}\\
1010\quad\underline{)\quad100\ 0100\quad}&\cdots&1001\\
1010\quad\underline{)\quad110\quad}&\cdots&1000\\
0\quad&\cdots&110
\end{array}$$
The first remainder, $1001_2=9_{10}$, becomes the least significant digit, and the last remainder, $110_2 = 6_{10}$, becomes the most significant digit:
$$10\ 1011\ 0001_2 = 689_{10}$$

The prerequisite is, you are good at doing division and subtraction in binary.

Comment: This is the fact, I'm not good at doing division in binary(I only know how to manage the division by 2(by right shifting the binary number)). And substractions aren't a big deal.

Comment: @Eugenio If you do not know binary division, why would you want to use binary division to convert a binary number to another base? This method is analogous to the common way of converting a decimal number to binary, in which the division is done in the original base, decimal.